# Failed building wheel for psycopg2 (Windows 11)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pip, psycopg2

I am building a Django project, and as I was installing the psycopg2(using virtual env), I kept getting an error.

Versions:

- Django==4.1.2
- Python==3.11.0
- PIP==22.3
- OS==Win11

Code:
`(env) PS C:\Users\keiko\Desktop\project> pip install psycopg2`

Error:

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2 
> Running setup.py clean for psycopg2 
> Failed to build psycopg2 
> Installing collected packages: psycopg2 
> Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: legacy-install-failure

I have already tried the solutions I found on the internet like:

1. Install psycopg2-binary instead.
   Code: `pip install psycopg2-binary`

> Error: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary

2. Upgrade the wheel and setup tools
   Code:

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install psycopg2
```

3. Install it with python
   Code: `python -m pip install psycopg2`

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2

4. Install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools

... but still none of these solutions helped me. I'm really hoping to install the package(psycopg2) on my project, I've been stuck with this error for so long and I can't really find any solution to this. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install libpq-dev`

Comment: I just tried it, but I get this error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpq-dev (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libpq-dev

Comment: I am having the same error using Windows 11 x64, and I also tried the solutions you have mentioned without positive results :(.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I had reinstall my python but with a lower version (3.10) and it worked for me :)

Comment: However, I want to use Python 3.11, so I hope it gets fixed soon.